# Titanium: Customization of Android Tab Group Bar and Tabs

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-mobile

I've built a tab bar on iOS using Objective-C and am trying to get the tab bar on Android to look as close as possible using Titanium. I'm wondering:

1. How do you give the tab bar itself a background image? The only thing I've been able to do is give it a background color. The `backgroundImage` property has no effect.
2. How do you change the selected tab's background color? I've tried changing the `activeTabBackgroundSelectedColor` with no luck.
3. How do you modify the active tab's icon? I would love for the icon to be grey when not selected, but white when selected. I've tried creating a drawable but I cannot get the Android app to recognize it using `Titanium.App.Android.R.drawable.ic_tab_coupon`
   Thanks for your help!

-

P.S. For what it's worth, here is a snippet of the code I'm working with. Note, I have other tabs that are instantiated/added the same way, I just haven't shown them for brevity.

```
var self = Ti.UI.createTabGroup({
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    activeTabBackgroundColor: 'blue',
});

var win1 = new Window(L('SpintoWin'));

var tab1 = Ti.UI.createTab({
    backgroundColor: 'none',
    title: L('SpintoWin'),
    icon: '/images/tab-icon-gift.png',
    window: win1
});

win1.containingTab = tab1;

self.addTab(tab1);
```

Comment: There was a good android tutorial for this, but it looks like they took it off their website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an older question but I figured I would provide some additional details about this since the question is pretty high in the search engine results for the terms.

http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/53851/android-tab-icon-states

In Titanium 1.7 tabs were modified to support a drawable resource to allow for this (see below, including sample code)

https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-3179

Now, somewhere after that fix the ability to specify a drawable resource as the icon for a tab was removed.

The next logical step was to try to modify the `.icon` property of your tab when it gained or lost focus as described in the following question:

http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/135063/how-to-change-active-tab-icon

Due to the fact that the native Android code takes a drawable resource and not a string value the icons on the tabs can not be updated after they are drawn:

https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-9962

So, the answer to the question is:

- You can not set the icon to a drawable resource
- You can not change the tabs icon after the tab is drawn

Until one of the above is avaliable you will be unable to change the icon of a tab when it is selected when you use Ti.UI.TabGroup / Ti.UI.Tab.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** You need to define `TabWidget`'s `android:background` attribute. For example:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@android:id/tabs" />

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

        android:background="@drawable/tab_backgrnd" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Where `tab_backgrnd` may be any [drawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html).

**2 & 3.** First you define the layout for the tab as Android itself does. Here is what Android's tab layout looks like:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="64dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-3dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="-3dip"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/tab_indicator">

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        style="?android:attr/tabWidgetStyle" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

You may put in this layout anything you want, not just one `ImageView` and one `TextView`. To make your tabs change when pressed/selected, set the [`StateListDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList) as the background of the root layout and the background of other elements, which the tab contains (`ImageView` and `TextView` in the example above).

Then you inflate this layout and set it as tab indicator:

```
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
    TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec;  // Reusable TabSpec for each tab
    Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab
    View tabView;
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, YourActivity1.class);
    tabView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_layout, tabHost.getTabWidget(), false);
    tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(TAG_TAB_1).setIndicator(tabView).setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

    // Do the same for the other tabs
    ...
```

You may set the icon and the text of each tab programmatically (as Android does utilizing `android:id="@+id/icon"` and `android:id="@+id/title"` ids) or you may define separate layouts for every tab.

Comment: I appreciate the lengthy response, but I'm asking for a solution using Titanium. I don't really want to build a new TabGroup module if I don't have to.

Comment: sorry, didn't get your question